# Network Topology using Graphs

Tags: java, implementation, graph-algorithm, topology

First of all hello everyone, this is my first post here. I am asking for your help, I'm designing a network topology for access points, but to make it more creative I want to do some coding on java. I want to code it using Graph data structure but what i may have a problem is like the following, i want to point some access points on the most frequent places. But whats the **best algorithm** to find the best places to put the AP's. Also is there any possible choice I could do double graph, one pair of graphs for people, and the other pair for AP's ? I would really appreciate your help cos I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Unfortunately, your question is likely too broad to be on-topic here (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for question quidelines and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for general asking tips.

Comment: sounds a Voronoi problem. I would research a little more first

Comment: There is software for this that will use actual floorplans and data collected from wireless site surveys to give a good first pass for AP and monitor placement and radio power settings. After you install the APs, you do another site survey to tweak the AP placement and radio power settings. Periodically, you need to use data collected in the WLC to adjust these.